# Why is my scoped dependency instantiated twice in single scope?

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-5

Lets say I have one Singleton that has one Scoped dependency (and is held by singleton forever).

Then I'm creating one scope and fetching both Singleton and Scoped instances from container.
I'd expect that Scoped is instantiated just once in a single scope.

Please have a look at a simplified code sample:

```
namespace TrivialConsole
{
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using System;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddScoped<Scoped>();
            services.AddSingleton<Singleton>();

            var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            using (var rootScope = provider.CreateScope())
            {
                var scopeProvider = rootScope.ServiceProvider;
                var singleton = scopeProvider.GetRequiredService<Singleton>();
                var scoped = scopeProvider.GetRequiredService<Scoped>();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Singleton
    {
        private static int instances = 0;

        private readonly Scoped scoped;

        public Singleton(Scoped scoped)
        {
            instances += 1;
            this.scoped = scoped;
            Console.WriteLine($"singleton {instances}");
        }
    }

    public class Scoped
    {
        private static int instances = 0;

        public Scoped()
        {
            instances += 1;
            Console.WriteLine($"scoped {instances}");
        }
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
scoped 1
singleton 1
scoped 2
```

Expected result ->

```
scoped 1
singleton 1
```

Comment: What I think is happening is that Singleton is available in every scope (lets call it global scope) and therefore it'll drag there also Scoped dependency instance (into global scope).
In root scope, Scoped will be created again since it is in different scope.

Comment: Also note the following about scope validation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#scope-validation

Comment: Scoped types are not suppose to be injected into singletons in this framework according to the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#scoped

Comment: Ah thanks @NKosi that makes sense now. Will you put it into answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scoped types are not suppose to be injected into singletons in this framework according to the documentation.

> Do not resolve a scoped service from a singleton and be careful not to
> do so indirectly, for example, through a transient service. It may
> cause the service to have incorrect state when processing subsequent
> requests. It's fine to:
>
> - Resolve a singleton service from a scoped or transient service.
> - Resolve a scoped service from another scoped or transient service.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#scoped)